# Using 4 nodes on 4 servers, 1 bucket with 3 replicas and items count changes after stoping one node

Tags: couchbase

I've been testing CouchBase to understand how replication and consistency works in CouchBase.

I've installed 4 nodes on 4 severs and created 1 bucket with 3 replicas and created appr 1500000 kv pairs.

After creating the data , I simply stop couchbase server on one of the nodes with the command (service couchbase-server stop)

And on admin interface, it shows me I have apprx 1000000 kv pairs and it was showing me the correct item count.

And the simple count views showing me the same results with erors messages telling me that one node is not available as :

```
{"rows":[
{"key":null,"value":1058754}
],
"errors":[
{"from":"http://192.168.100.9:8092/_view_merge/?limit=10","reason":"{econnrefused,[{lhttpc_client,send_request,1},\n {lhttpc_client,execute,9},\n {lhttpc_client,request,9}]}"}
]
}
```

I do understand the error info but why item counts get changed like that , even I've set the bucket with 3 replicas ?

Comment: Did you try to do rebalance after stop?

Comment: I do not think manuel rebalance needed with 3 replicas.

Comment: In production normally autofailover option should be enabled. This means that unavailable node will be removed after timeout from cluster and it will be rebalanced automatically. Try to rebalance and check result. Also maybe it just was not enough time to replicate data from one node to antoher if you shutdown one node just after adding data.

Comment: I've tested your suggestion just with 500 items and waited the reblancing get stady.Result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a node disappeared from the cluster (stop or failure) the data are not available until the failover occurs. (this could be manual or automatic).

You need to failover the node to get all the data available, and most of the time you do a rebalance after a fail over.

See http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-admin-tasks-failover.html